# How to get the index of element inside nested Lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have class which looks like this :

```
public class Payment
{
    public List<string> Base { get; set; }
    public List<string> Interest { get; set; }
}
```

Then, later in my code I want to feed a `Repeater` only with the values from `List<string> Base` so I try to create an array of anonymous objects using `LINQ` and I need in this anonymous object to have a property `Id` where `Id = IndexOf(x.Base)`. So i tried this :

```
RpBase.DataSource = PymentsList.Select(x => new { Base = x.Base, Id = PymentsList.IndexOf(x.Base) });
```

But it's not working. Writing this it's starting to make sense that I need to select from the `<Base>` list, of each `x` but I don't know how to write it `LINQ` still it seems to me that this should be doable.

Comment: Can you clarify what your `DataSource` should be? Is it all the strings from `Base` for all the payments in your payment list or is it only the list of strings from `Base` for a single Payment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
RpBase.DataSource = PymentsList.SelectMany(x=>x.Base)
                               .Select((x,i)=>new { Base = x, Id =i})
```

Comment: `LINQ` is amazing： The more you use, the more you realize it's charm

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like that ?

```
RpBase.DataSource = PymentsList.Base.Select((x,i) => new { Base = x, Id = i });
```

if `PymentsList` is a list of `Payment`, use `.SelectMany(x => x.Base)` instead of `.Base`

**Edit :** @Tim.Tang has done the good answer faster ^^